# On Android, do gesture events work on the emulator?

Tags: android

I am trying to detect gesture events on the emulator by making mouse clicks, should this work?  I've tried double clicking (which i would expect to produce a onDoubleTap), clicking (which I would expect to produce a onSingleTapConfirmed), and dragging (to hopeful produce a onScroll), but these all produce the same three series of events: onDown, onShowPress, onLongPress.

Is there a particular way mouse clicks/drags must be made to produce gesture events on the emulator?  Or is there something wrong with the below code, which I am using to detect events:

```
public class GestureEnabledImageView extends ImageView implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener
{
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    public GestureEnabledImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
        gestureScanner.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    public GestureEnabledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet atts)
    {
        super(context, atts);
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
        gestureScanner.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    public GestureEnabledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet atts, int style)
    {
        super(context, atts, style);
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
        gestureScanner.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
    {
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onDown: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        log("onFling: " + e1.getX() + ", " + e1.getY() + " -- " + e2.getX() + ", " + e2.getY() + " -- " + velocityX + " -- " + velocityY);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onLongPress: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        log("onScroll: " + e1.getX() + ", " + e1.getY() + " -- " + e2.getX() + ", " + e2.getY() + " -- " + distanceX + " -- " + distanceY);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        log("onShowPress: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        System.out.println();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onSingleTapUp: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onDoubleTap: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onDoubleTapEvent: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
    {
        log("onSingleTapConfirmed: " + e.getRawX() + ", " +e.getRawY());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private void log(String text)
    {
        Log.i("MyInfo", text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found the solution, just wanted to post here for anyone else with similar problems:

The gestureListener methods should return "true", not "false".  This is surprising, because the documentation states that returning "true" indicates that the event has been consumed, which, I would think, would keep further MotionEvents from being fired.  But, apparently not...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for so late answer :)
Quotation from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

> Whether or not you use GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, it's best practice to implement an onDown() method that returns true. This is because all gestures begin with an onDown() message. If you return false from onDown(), as GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener does by default, the system assumes that you want to ignore the rest of the gesture, and the other methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener never get called. This has the potential to cause unexpected problems in your app. The only time you should return false from onDown() is if you truly want to ignore an entire gesture.

So, the answer is simple: you have just to implement `onDown()` that returns `true`.